# Can a string in infix notation be converted to prefix notation using only queues ? (consider the case where the only operations are + and -)

Tags: java, string, queue, prefix, infix-notation

```
public class Convert{ 
/* the algorithm works as follows after inserting all elements of infix string 
into an empty Queue iterate over queue for infix.length() number of times and 
check if element at front of queue is an operator if yes enque the element to 
back of the queue else deque the operand and concatenate it with the empty 
prefix string here is an example then finally deque the queue elements with 
the prefix string*/                  

    public static String Pre(String in){
        int i = 0;
        Queue Q = new Queue(in.length());     //assuming a Queue of characters
        while(i<in.length()){
            Q.enque(in.charAt(i));       
        }
        i = in.length()-1;
        String pre = "";
        while(i>=0){                         //move operators to end of queue
            if(Q.peek()=='+'||'-'){           //if character is oper enque at end 
                Q.enque(Q.deque);}
            else{
                pre  = pre + Q.deque;
            }            // concatenate operands with prefix 
        }
        while(!Q.isEmpty) {                        //concatenate the operators 
            pre = Q.deque + pre;
        }
        return pre;                               // end of method
    }
}
```

Comment: I don't really understand how your given code is supposed to supplement your question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A "[Post](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Emil_Post)" [Production System](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Post_canonical_system) uses only queues. It has equivalent power to a Turing Machine.

Answer (score 0):

Given the very limited grammar you specified, to me it appears that you could convert infix to prefix using a double-ended queue.  Were the grammar more complex I doubt that this approach would work.

Comment: Sorry I wasn't very clear, I assume the string is not bracketed and the only operations are + and - and this is a normal queue where I deque from the front and enque to the rear